# Where can I find practice for given atom instructions, implement ME

Tags: distributed-systems

I'm trying to practice for my upcoming distributed systems test.  My teacher said that their will be a problem where he'll give us atomic instructions and we're going to have to implement Mutual Exclusion (ME) using those instructions.

Where can I find practice problems/solutions for these types of problems?  I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Comment: Look at past exams.